# Selenium Webdriver script works on html code of Debugging mode(F12) or View Source(ctrl +U)?

Tags: html, selenium, webdriver

I've made a selenium WebDriver script which looks for Meta tags of Breadcrumbs present in a webpage. But this meta tag for "Home" page(first breadcrumb) is not visible on Debugging mode while it is visible on Source Code(ctrl +U). Meta tag for rest of the breadcrumbs are visible on debugging mode. The scripts is not able to find the meta tag for "Home" page so does this mean that Selenium Webdriver script only works on code visible through Debugging mode? Is there any way to solve this issue?

Following is the Meta tag which is not visible on Debugging Mode but visible on source code:

```
<meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
```

URL to test: 
https://www.ennovatesoftware.com/en-gb/international-courier-services/tanzania-parcel-delivery

```
List <WebElement> breadcrumbs=null;
driver.get("https://www.ennovatesoftware.com/en-gb/international-courier-services/tanzania-parcel-delivery");
breadcrumbs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*@id='newBreadCrumb']/div/ul/li"));

            if(breadcrumbs.size()==0)
            {System.out.println("No BreadCrumbs present");
        continue;
            }
            else 
            {   
             try{
            if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='newBreadCrumb']/div/ul")).getAttribute("itemtype").equals("http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList"))
                {
                    for (WebElement W: breadcrumbs)
                    { 
                        bc=bc+1;
                try{
if( Integer.parseInt( W.findElement(By.tagName("meta")).getAttribute("content"))==bc && W.findElement(By.tagName("meta")).getAttribute("itemprop").equals("position"))
                    p=p+1;
                       }
                catch(Exception e)
                    {}
                     }
                }
            }
                catch(Exception e)
                {System.out.println("Fail");}
            }

            if(p==bc)
                System.out.println("Pass");
            else
                System.out.println("Fail");
```

Comment: That is really weird... javascript in the Chrome devtools won't find that first tag either but finds the other two. `document.querySelectorAll("meta[itemprop='position']")`

Comment: Yes that's what is baffling me. Please help me find a workaround.